# Read columns in dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as below:-

Emplid,Name_x,Age_x,Name_y,Age_y
1,ABC,23,ABC,23
2,XYZ,24,PQR,24

I want to compare Name_x with Name_y & Age_x with Age_y values , if they match I add additional record saying all values matched ( as in 1st case) & if any of column doesnt match it should say "<column_name> not matched for Emplid" ( as in 2nd case it should say "age didnt match for empl_id 2)

My column names will be changing each time based on user input , so i have it currently captured in list & i am trying to scan the column list using for loop , but doesnt work fine .

Any leads on what approach or sudo code i can use ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're trying to check values in 2 columns.

```
df['new_column'] = np.where(df['Name_x']==df['Name_y'], 'matched names', 'no_match')
```

This adds a column saying the names match, if not it will say they haven't matched. You can loop through this with some added code for other columns